# How to access Post data to access login data in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, http-post

How to access the login authentication by the `POST DATA` in the below and it get from the httpFox to login the website. In other time i try to testing whether the `GetRequestStreamCallback()` operation will work and i found that the operation are not working and it end on the `DoWork()`. Why it not continue do the `GetRequestStreamCallback()` operation. Thanks For Helping me.

POST DATA

```
Parameter                         value
__EVENTTARGET
__EVENTARGUMENT
__VIEWSTATE                       /wEPDwUIMTQwOTY1MTgPZBYCAgMPZBYEAgEPZBYCZg9kFgICAQ9kFgJmD2QWAgINDxAPFgIeB0NoZWNrZWRoZGRkZAIFDzwrAAgCAA8WBB4PRGF0YVNvdXJjZUJvdW5kZx4OXyFVc2VWaWV3U3RhdGVnZAYPFgIeCklzU2F2ZWRBbGxnDxQrAAkUKwABFgIeDlJ1bnRpbWVDcmVhdGVkZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZxQrAAEWAh8EZ2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgICAg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFgZmD2QWBmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh4ISW1hZ2VVcmwFG34vcHJvZHVjdGltYWdlL0NBRDAwNTQ3LmpwZ2RkAgMPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQhDQUQwMDU0N2RkAgUPDxYCHwYFVENBUkQgUFJFUFJJTlQgS0lOT0tVTklZQSBQVkMgSVNPIDAuNzZNTSA1QyAxQyAgRk9SIFBSRVBSSU5UIEtJTk9LVU5JWUEgQ0FSRCBERVNJR04gMmRkAgcPDxYCHwYFD1BSRVBSSU5URUQgQ0FSRGRkAgIPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh8FBRt+L3Byb2R1Y3RpbWFnZS9CQVIwMTE1NC5qcGdkZAIDDw8WAh8GBQhCQVIwMTE1NGRkAgUPDxYCHwYFLEdGUzQ0NzAgR1JZUEhPTiBHRlM0NDAwIEZJWEVEIFNDQU5ORVIgMkQgVVNCZGQCBw8PFgIfBgUHR1JZUEhPTmRkAgQPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh8FBRt+L3Byb2R1Y3RpbWFnZS9CQVIwMTE1My5qcGdkZAIDDw8WAh8GBQhCQVIwMTE1M2RkAgUPDxYCHwYFVkJDUDgwMDBFWFQ1IEVYVEVOREVEIDUgKDQrMSkgWUVBUlMgTUFOVUZBQ1RVUklORyBERUZFQ1QgV0FSUkFOVFkgQkNQODAwMCBEQVRBIFRFUk1JTkFMZGQCBw8PFgIfBgUPQkFSQ09ERSBTQ0FOTkVSZGQCAg9kFgZmD2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFggCAQ8PFgIfBQUbfi9wcm9kdWN0aW1hZ2UvQkFSMDExNTIuanBnZGQCAw8PFgIfBgUIQkFSMDExNTJkZAIFDw8WAh8GBVZCQ1A4MDAwRVhUMyBFWFRFTkRFRCAzICgyKzEpIFlFQVJTIE1BTlVGQUNUVVJJTkcgREVGRUNUIFdBUlJBTlRZIEJDUDgwMDAgREFUQSBURVJNSU5BTGRkAgcPDxYCHwYFD0JBUkNPREUgU0NBTk5FUmRkAgIPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh8FBRt+L3Byb2R1Y3RpbWFnZS9CQVIwMTE1MS5qcGdkZAIDDw8WAh8GBQhCQVIwMTE1MWRkAgUPDxYCHwYFTFBIRDIwMjI2MTAxIFRQSCBUSEVSTUFMIFBSSU5USEVBRCAyMDNEUEkgRk9SIERBVEFNQVggRE1YIE0gQ0xBU1MgTUlJIFBSSU5URVJkZAIHDw8WAh8GBQ9EQVRBTUFYIE0gQ0xBU1NkZAIED2QWAmYPZBYCZg9kFggCAQ8PFgIfBQUbfi9wcm9kdWN0aW1hZ2UvQkFSMDExNTAuanBnZGQCAw8PFgIfBgUIQkFSMDExNTBkZAIFDw8WAh8GBTlCQ1A4MDAwIERBVEEgVEVSTUlOQUwgTEFTRVIgMU1CLzRNQiBSUzIzMiBVU0IgQ0FCTEUgQkxBQ0tkZAIHDw8WAh8GBQ9CQVJDT0RFIFNDQU5ORVJkZAIED2QWBmYPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh8FBRt+L3Byb2R1Y3RpbWFnZS9CQVIwMTE0OS5qcGdkZAIDDw8WAh8GBQhCQVIwMTE0OWRkAgUPDxYCHwYFPFBNNDNBMDEwMDAwMDAzMDEgUE00M0EgNC41SU5DSCAzMDBEUEkgRlQgUk9XIEVUSEVSTkVUIDEyOE1CIGRkAgcPDxYCHwYFBVBNNDNBZGQCAg9kFgJmD2QWAmYPZBYIAgEPDxYCHwUFG34vcHJvZHVjdGltYWdlL0JBUjAxMTQ4LmpwZ2RkAgMPDxYCHwYFCEJBUjAxMTQ4ZGQCBQ8PFgIfBgVhWlNONVNLUjUxIFNLT1JQSU9YMyAxNFdPUktJTkcgREFZUyBUVVJOQVJPVU5EIEVBU0UgT0YgQ0FSRSBDT01QUkVIRU5TSVZFIENPVkVSQUdFIDUtWUVBUiBQQUNLQUdFRGRkAgcPDxYCHwYFCVNLT1JQSU9YM2RkAgQPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWCAIBDw8WAh8FBRt+L3Byb2R1Y3RpbWFnZS9TVkMwMDEyNC5qcGdkZAIDDw8WAh8GBQhTVkMwMDEyNGRkAgUPDxYCHwYFSVNFTlRJTkVMIDIwMTIgREFUQSBFWENIQU5HRSBJTlNUQUxMQVRJT04gVEVTSU5HIEFORCBUUkFJTklORyBPTlNJVEUgMSBEQVlkZAIHDw8WAh8GBQhTRU5USU5BTGRkGAIFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYCBRxMb2dpblZpZXcxJExvZ2luMSRSZW1lbWJlck1lBQ1BU1B4RGF0YVZpZXcxBQ1BU1B4RGF0YVZpZXcxDxQrAAdkZmYCA2YCFGdkMBSkuj/XQpQVVL41154MjHTriF3AqkB5ahYmcD10itw=
__EVENTVALIDATION                 /wEWBgLiiri0BQKRyKzhAgKUxtegDAKi77CUBwKd6MPGBALNx9K3CuAiLP9Qxn4q+Nwy4Hl2t5zaXX+GadHLKCF8sJn6YTar
LoginView1$Login1$UserName        USERNAME
LoginView1$Login1$Password        PASSWORD
LoginView1$Login1$LoginButton     Log In
ASPxDataView1                     0;3;3
DXScript                          1_141,1_79,1_123,1_82
```

The below code is my work so far.

```
public void DoWork()
    {
        var url = "xxxxxxxx";
        // Create the web request object
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        // Start the request
        webRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback), webRequest);    
    }
void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
    // End the stream request operation
    Stream postStream = webRequest.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
    // Create the post data
    // Demo POST data 
    string postData = 
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Add the post data to the web request
    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    postStream.Close();
    // Start the web request
    webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), webRequest);
}

void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response;
        // End the get response operation
        response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
        var Response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamResponse.Close();
        streamReader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        // Error treatment
        // ...
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoWork();
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".